# Transpose a split range into a variant array

Tags: excel, vba

Morning all, I just tried something and it didn't work.

If I use this function:

```
Public Function GetPeople()
    GetPeople = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(wsPeople.Range("A2:A10").Value2)
End Function
```

I get a 1D variant / array of 9 strings with the values in cells from A2:A10

I'm trying to do the same for a split range:

```
Public Function GetPeople2()
    GetPeople2 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(wsPeople.Range("A2,A5,A10").Value2)
End Function
```

But it only returns the value from `A2` and not all three like I wanted.

In reality this split range is defined by a helper column with an "x" - any rows marked "x" will need to be included in this split range.

**What is the simplest way** to get the same 1D variant array of strings as a function return, but by using a split range?

It's probably just a classic cycling through rows but wondered if `.Transpose` could still be used.

Comment: You need to use a loop.

Comment: Yeah I tried a few things, nothing worked, ended up looping!

Comment: @jamheadart - posted a simple Office 365 VBA solution as one-liner thus avoiding a loop :-) hth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Office 365 solution (via contiguous range reference)**

> *In reality this split range is defined by a **helper column** with an "x" - any rows marked "x" will need to be included in this split range.*

This allows to pass the entire (contiguous) data column range as function argument evaluating the condition *only `"x"`* using the new worksheet function `FILTER()` with its dynamic **Office 365** possibilities.

This allows to get the wanted data directly instead of going the long way round creating a *non contiguous* range reference first and you can code a one-liner:

```
Public Function GetPeopleX(rng As Range, _
                           Optional ByVal criteria = "x", _
                           Optional ByVal myOffset As Long = 1)
    GetPeopleX = Application.Transpose(Evaluate("=Filter(" & rng.Address & "," & rng.Offset(, myOffset).Address & "=""" & criteria & ""","""")"))
End Function
```

**Example call**

```
Sub ExampleCall()
Debug.Print Join(GetPeopleX(Sheet1.Range("A2:A10")), ", ")
End Sub
```

**Addendum**

If it's probable that there isn't at least one row marked by `x` you could add the following error handling to the function `GetPeopleX()`:

```
    On Error Resume Next
        Debug.Print UBound(GetPeopleX)   ' << force possible error if nothing found
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then GetPeopleX = Array(): Err.Clear
```

As the error handling returns only a declared array without entries (LBound: 0, Ubound: -1), this allows to use `Join()` for any result, but to check for positive array results in the calling routine via boundaries. So an items count could be done via `LBound()`.

**Filter() function**

The WorksheetFunction itself building the basis of `GetPeopleX()` in a simplified form could be

```
=FILTER(A2:A10,B2:B10="x","")
```

> Syntax: `=FILTER(array,include,[if_empty])`

c.f. Help Reference [Filter function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/filter-function-f4f7cb66-82eb-4767-8f7c-4877ad80c759)

Comment: Nice, I can't try this right now (my laptop has xl 2010, yuk) but I will give it a shot on my work laptop later!